# Jmeter- With Distributed testing Execution start has a huge delay

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am doing distributed Testing in Jmeter. 
I have 2 Slave and 1 Master machine. When I am running the script in the distributed environment in both the machines it is showing (Starting test on host....) in cmd prompt in Slave machine.
But the execution starts after a long time. Sometime it is very late so that I need to stop it.
Note: I am also using Perfmon Metrics collector

Jmeter Log

```
2014/07/17 12:42:42 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2014/07/17 12:42:42 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run
```

Please let me know if I need to add any more info

Comment: It is bound to start with a delay, since your Jmeter script is in Controller. every time you run the test in distributed environment, first the script is transferred to all the slaves and then the execution starts.

Comment: It will not affect the Response time right? Is there any way to optimize that? And how to get the running status? In GUI mode we had the Green symbol with thread count. But in Non GUI mode how can I get the running status?

Comment: It will not affect the response time, since Jmeter will not consider the time before actual test starts. In Non-GUI mode you will have to check the results in "*.JLT" output file. you can even download this file to  your local machine and load it in summary/aggregate report listeners for viewing it graphically.